# Facebook messages to multiple people: do they all know who I sent it to?

Tags: facebook, privacy

When I send Facebook messages to more than one person by adding them all to the **to** field, does everyone who receives the message see that I've sent it to more than one person? Can they see who?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will be just like an email where you can see everyone the message was sent to and will be able to reply to the sender or reply to everyone the message was sent to.

Comment: It's a bit annoying, actually. Have to be careful when replying to a message, because it will go to all the recipients of the original message.